# Scrapy - not able to scrape ratings data on Amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape ratings data from an Amazon storefront. Consider the following link as an example -

https://www.amazon.in/s?me=A2ABGQT3TTW1NZ&marketplaceID=A21TJRUUN4KGV

While I am successful in scraping data points such as name, rating out of 5, price, etc. I am unable to scrape the number of ratings. This is stored under the following -

844

```
def parse(self, response):
    for a in response.xpath("//div[@class='s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col s-widget-spacing-small sg-col-12-of-16']"):
        yield {
            'ASIN' : a.xpath("//@data-asin").get(),
            'Name' : a.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']/text()").get(),
            'Rating' : a.xpath(".//span[@class='a-icon-alt']/text()").get(),
            'No. of Ratings' : a.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-base']/text()").get(),
            'ASP' : a.xpath(".//span[@class='a-price-whole']/text()").get()
        }
```

The number of ratings is coming as **None**.

The surprising part is that it was working fine till a few days back. Kindly help me out with this.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
'No. of Ratings' : a.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-base']/text()").get(),
```

into

```
'No. of Ratings' : a.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'a-size-base')]/text()").get()
```

Because the class of that span is "a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text"

Comment: Hey, this works, thanks a lot!!! Just one query, when I inspect the ratings element I see the following -

<span class="a-size-base">846</span>

How did you figure that the class is "a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text"?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think you are using firefox or some other web browser. If you are using firefox, you will see "a-size-base". If you are using chrome, you will see "a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text". Many website change it's class in different browser.

Comment: I see the same on both browsers, but I see "a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text" on Safari. Thanks for the explanation, learnt some thing new :)